# QtCreator crashes on registering namespace

Tags: qt, crash, qt5

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 (Desktop) x64 on my computer and wanted to install Qt5 with QtCreator. So, I downloaded it from:

http://qt-project.org/downloads

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/online_installers/1.4/qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-2-x86_64-online.run

After I got the installation running, by executing the .run file from the terminal, I tried to start QtCreator.

It starts up, but within a minute it crashes. When I try to launch QtCreator from the Terminal by running the bash script in:

/opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh

The same thing happends, but it crashes with the following message:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'QHelpCollectionHandler-20391584-4', old connection removed.
QSqlQuery::prepare: no driver
QSqlQuery::prepare: no driver
Error registering namespace ' "org.qt-project.qtgui.502" ' from file ' "/opt/Qt//5.0.2/gcc_64/doc/qtgui.qch" ': "Cannot register namespace 'org.qt-project.qtgui.502'!" 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The last message 'Segmentation fault' looks like some kind of buffer overflow to me.

I googled around for a bit, but my search turned up nothing. I was unable to find a solution, or even somebody with the same problem.

Does anyone know what causes QtCreator to crash, and how I can fix this? Or does somebody have some options I can try to get this thing working?

P.S I of course tried re-installing and turning the computer off and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little older version on the official repositories:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qt5-default
$ sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

You can also install QtCreator 2.8.1 from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu_sdk_release/saucy/main/base/qtcreator) (I'm using this package).